# Ansible exit expect from virsh console

Tags: ansible

Code:

```
- expect:
    command: virsh console myguest
    responses:
      'Escape character is': ''
      'root>': 'show interfaces em0 | grep Current'
    timeout: 5
  register: result
```

This task will hang forever. I believe it was because of after finishing the show interface command, the system still get back to the 'root>' prompt for next command, and because of my 'root>' response provided, the prompt-response got into a dead loop.

I know ideally I could provided 2 responses as list to 'root>', one would be the show command, the other would be Ctrl-]. But there is no text expression of Ctrl-], I cannot really provide it.

So I set the timeout, hoped it would just loop up to 5 seconds. But that's not the case.
I set the single response as list item, but the task error out for next response.

So what I can do to run the show command in virsh console, and then get out of it, so my playbook can continue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\u001d` to represent `^]` (CTRL-]) and allow the expect call to either complete successfully, or timeout and fail.

Also, you can add `ignore_errors: true` to allow you to process the error rather than have Ansible fail immediately. For example:

```
- expect:
    command: "virsh console {{ guest }}"
    responses:
      'Escape character is': ''
      'root>': 
        - 'show interfaces em0 | grep Current'
        - "\u001d"
    register: expect_response
    ignore_errors: true
- debug:
    msg: "Expect failed with rc={{ expect_response.rc }}"
  when: expect_response.failed
```

Comment: Hi @Sean Safron, thanks so much to take the time to response. Your answer looking good! I already bypassed the need of this answer last time. I'll try your answer when I get a chance next time and update here.